# Dimensionality reduction with discrete comparisons

Tags: categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction

I have data from many people with the following shape (from a survey):

$a$ is more similar to $b$ than $c$

where $a, b, c$ are visual stimuli. I would like to visualize the data in a nice one-dimensional order or two-dimensional arrangement, but I am unsure how to do this based just on the data I have.

Is there an existing method to do dimensionality reduction with data with that shape, or is there a way to transform the data to make it easier?